# RIA Services library and resource strings in meta attributes

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, data-annotations

I've split out my domain services into a separate WCF RIA Services Class Library project. However there now seems to be a problem with using the resource strings in the client side library.

e.g.

The client project library has generated code like this:

```
[DataMember()]
[Display(Description="FullNameDescription", Name="FullNameLabel", Order=-1, ResourceType=typeof(MetadataStrings))]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName="BadFullNameLength", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(MetadataStrings))]
public string FullName
{
 // ...
}
```

where MetadataStrings is a resource file in the class library. This class library is then referenced by the silverlight project.

But the meta attributes that use ResourceType cause the designer to throw an exception when opening a view and at runtime cause a MissingManifestResourceException.

If I comment out the attributes and rebuild it all works fine. So something is not right with the resources being in another assembly i'm guessing?

Edit: Nevermind finally got this working, problem was that i renamed my class library projects and the namespace of the resource file was wrong. 3 days wasted.

Comment: When you say "I have split out"... does that mean you did not start with a WCF RIA services class library, but migrated it to a lib afterwards? Can you clarify what projects you have linked to what projects?

Comment: I started with a normal silverlight app containing two projects. The domain services were in the "Web" project. Then created a class library and moved the domain services into there. SO i now have 4 projects: Silverlight, Silverlight.Web, ClassLib, and ClassLib.Web. Silverlight refs ClassLib, Silverlight.Web refs ClassLib.Web

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as resolved.